# ListView setOnItemClickListener not working by adding button

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with text and button in each row, list view setOnItemClickListener() is not working. is it possible to handle item click and button click events differently(item click should call ActivityA and button click should call ActivityB). Does anyone have a solution

```
    private ArrayList<String> userIDArr = null;
    private ArrayList<String> userNameArr = null;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper = null;
    private ListView userListView=null; 


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
          setContentView(R.layout.list_view);         
          dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());        
          Map<String,ArrayList<String>> displayMap = dbHelper.getUserListToDisplay();
          userIDArr = displayMap.get("UserID");
          userNameArr = displayMap.get("FirstName1");           


          userListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
          userListView.setAdapter(new UserListAdapter(this,userIDArr));


          userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                  Toast.makeText(usersListActivity.this,
                            "Item in position " + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
            });
     }


    public class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        Activity context;
        public UserListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> names) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, names);
            this.context = context;
        }
        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView UserNameAndID;
            public TextView Description;
            public Button  UploadBtn;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.UserNameAndID = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.User_detailsTxt);
                holder.Description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.User_status);
                holder.UploadBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.uploadbutton);
                holder.UploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

                        public void onClick(View v) {  
                        Toast.makeText(usersListActivity.this," Button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }   
                    }); 
                    rowView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }
            String s = userNameArr.get(position)+","+userIDArr.get(position);
            holder.UserNameAndID.setText(s);
            holder.Description.setText("U r in middle");
            return rowView;
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Try setting your buttons (or any other views you want to handle click inside a list item) like this:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: @Ben Lee: I added these to my checkboxes! Still not working. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` solves mine. I use two TextView in a custom LinearLayout row. Yuk android...

Comment: Someone get more details why setting like this?

Comment: ImageButton will not work. In list item view contains ImageButton, set android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".

Comment: adding android:clickable="false" can also be required (toggle it on, and off, in the layout designer to get it explicitly added to the XML)

Comment: Saved me too. Any idea on why is ListView acting like this?

Comment: android:setselectable and android:setclickable should be set to "false"

Comment: finally - fully customized listView, both single and multi choice managed by widget! but i'm still really wonder - how it works and why do we need to set focusable?

Comment: Warning: In case that you are using a ImageButton you need to use setFocusable(false) cause the constructor of ImageButton would enabe this attribute after inflate from xml file. But good answer though

Comment: Good call, this worked with a custom item composed of two textviews and an imageView.

Comment: this works, but for that the property `android: clickable` must be false for the "view" in question.

Attention to the parents of the "View" to be not using "android: clickable" on. this will block the pattern selector of your list or derivative.

You can match the pattern selector with a custom selector using the property `android: foreground` like this:

`<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <FrameLayout "android: foreground="CUSTOM SELECTOR"">
    <RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout/>
  <.../>
<.../>`

Comment: Yes it works with above attributes without setting clickable attribute.

Answer (score 122):

Sometimes the List will still not be able to make the Click Listener to pass. And at this case you might have to add one more attribute.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

And this attribute has to be added to the top most layout of your XML where you have provided the ListView elements.

Comment: Just so no-one else does what I just did: This will be undesirable if you have something requiring focus in your row like an EditText. I feel stupid now.

Comment: In my case this advice has helped. I have a TextView and RadioButton, the 1st hadn't clicked, the 2nd hadn't select the TextView. I wrote "android:clickable="false"" in RadioButton.

Comment: This is the solution when the button is an ImageButton

Comment: Curiously, this solution worked for me. The OnItemClickListener works without affecting the descendant events. Not sure why it worked, so... go figure.

Answer (score 15):

If you have an active view/focusable view in your list view then it will disable `onItemClickListener`... you can try to make it unfocusable by adding:
`android:focusable="false"` to any view that is usually focusable.

Answer (score 8):

Batter thing is to add both `Listener` to the whole of the `rowView` and to the `Button` inside `Adapter`.
Something like this.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
            View rowView = convertView;
            if(rowView == null)
            {
                    //intialize rowView, and set onclick listener only once.
                    rowView = someIntilizationMehhodOrInflatorMethod();
                    //add listener to the button also and also to the row view
                    rowView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
            //all your inflation and setting values goes here and at the end,
            //set position as tag to get the correct position, rather buggy one.
            rowView.setTag(String.valueOf(position));


            return rowView;
    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            //now get the tag of View v and convert it to integer.
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            Toast.makeText(context,"Item in position " + pos + " clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this even remotely better? You are creating an onClickListener for EVERY data element vs only 1 listener. You're example doesn't even recycle which views.

Comment: @J.Romero this was just an example, although there is loot of room for code optimization. However I've just updated the code.

Answer (score 5):

Try set `setClickable(false)` for each `Button`, `ImageButton`, etc and `View` like this:

```
view.setClickable(false);
button.setClickable(false);
imagebutton.setClickable(false);
```

Also you have to add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to main(first level) layout

Comment: I've found set blocksDescendants is enough, no need to cancel focusable etc. Android 4.1

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding button add `ImageView` and provide `setOnItemClcik` listener which would work fine.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
     if(convertView == null) {
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtubesearchrow, null);
         mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
         mViewHolder.alarm = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm);
         convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
     } else {
         mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }

     mViewHolder.tvTitle = detail(convertView, R.id.tvTitle,    
     // mViewHolder.tvDesc  = detail(convertView, R.id.tvDesc,  
     mViewHolder.ivIcon  = detail_image(convertView, R.id.ivIcon,  

     mViewHolder.alarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

        return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting the same error. If in the list layout you have any button to replace it with `TextView` i.e `ImageButton` with `ImageView`. For Reference their is my code:

```
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<ItemList> itemListsItems;

private Bookmark_SharedPref pref;

ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter_Item(Activity activity,List<ItemList> itemListsItems){
    this.activity=activity;
    this.itemListsItems=itemListsItems;
    pref = new Bookmark_SharedPref(activity);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemListsItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemListsItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(inflater == null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    if(imageLoader == null){
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    }




     holder.img = (NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
    holder.Title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    holder.Cat = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_category);

    holder.id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemid);

    holder.Desc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

    holder.book = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_star);



    // getting blog data or the row
    ItemList il = itemListsItems.get(position);

    //setting image
    holder.img.setImageUrl(il.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);

    // setting title
    holder.Title.setText(il.getTitle());

    //setting category
    holder.Cat.setText(il.getCategory());


    //setting blog id
    holder.id.setText(il.getId());

    //setting description
    holder.Desc.setText(il.getDescription());

    //bookmarking the post
    holder.book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            itemListsItems.get(position).isFav = !itemListsItems.get(position).isFav;
            ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_star)).setImageResource(itemListsItems.get(position).isFav ? R.mipmap.active_star : R.mipmap.inactive_star);

            if(itemListsItems.get(position).isFav){
                String data = Integer.toString(itemListsItems.get(position).id);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"fav hai "+data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pref.addPref(data);
            } else {
                String data = Integer.toString(itemListsItems.get(position).id);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"not fav"+ data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pref.removePref(data);
            }
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_star)).setImageResource(itemListsItems.get(position).isFav ? R.mipmap.active_star : R.mipmap.inactive_star);

    /*
    if(itemListsItems.get(position).isFav){
        String data = Integer.toString(itemListsItems.get(position).id);
        Toast.makeText(convertView.getContext(),"fav hai "+data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pref.addPref(data);
    } else {
        String data = Integer.toString(itemListsItems.get(position).id);
        //Toast.makeText(convertView.getContext(),"not fav"+ data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pref.removePref(data);
    }
    */
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
   public TextView Title, Desc,Cat,id;
    ImageView book;
    NetworkImageView img;
}
```

Also keep in mind to make list layout as `android:focussable="true"` and for that button/text parameter use `android:focussable="false"`.

Comment: *corrected* it should be _android:focusable="false"_ not focussable

Answer (score 1):

Make the parent clickable attribute to false like this `android:clickable="false"`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Again facing problem, then for all the child views add this clickable false.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:focusable="false"` attribute to button and to parent view add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` attribute like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sell_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sell" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's amazing to noticed that how XML changed causes the setonitemclicked in java Worked for me..

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but sometimes when you set the adapter, the listeners are cleared. Then, you must call `setOnClickListener` after `setAdapter` or `setListAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:clickable="true"` from the internal custome view from the `ListView`.