# ListView Listener not Working

Tags: android

I've seen a few examples on here to this problem, but none have solved this issue, observe the code below:

```
mProductList = hotdealhelper.getCatalog(getResources());
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewoffers);
myListView.setAdapter(new hotdealadapter(mProductList, getLayoutInflater()));



myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
      long id) {
        System.out.println("Newbie");
    }});
```

I have it in my oncreate lethod, and when I click on a particular position in the list, it is not printing the system.out. I am wondering why this is, I have used this exact code in another class and it works fine. I have the list in a activity class also. Below is the xml if it helps.

> ```
> <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/dealheader" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ImageView>
> <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/listViewoffers" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_marginTop="35px"></ListView>
> <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="0px" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></Button>
> ```

Comment: what does the listview row layout look like?

Comment: maybe you're seeing this bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414 if you have a checkbox or something in your listview.

Comment: print a System.out inside onCreate() and see if it is printing or not and then tell me if it is printing.

Comment: @JohnBoker I have no specified the row. However I do have a button in my view, could this be the problem you have said? AndroidKiller, yes the system.out prints in the oncreate.

Comment: yeah, remove the button and see if it works... if it does that was the problem.

Comment: fancy that! It works a charm. Add you answer down below so I can select it as correct

Comment: This happened to me earlier..
Try doing this, You should try this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button/6703671#6703671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten the @Override

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
      long id) {
        System.out.println("Newbie");
    }});
```

***EDIT***

Maybe you're seeing this bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414 if you have a checkbox or something in your listview.  remove the button and see if it works... if it does that was the problem.

Comment: Added it in and still no response from the listner

Answer (score 0):

Remove System.out.println

Try with `Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)` to check if click listner works