# Android list view setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-emulator

I want to hide the edit text and button field initially in list view and show that edit text and button for a particular raw in list view when that raw is clicked.So I tried to set the height to 0 in layout xml and then set it to some other value when user clicks on a raw, but it is not working I think my list view click event is not working.
In the Android layout that I have list view there are Image view as a button, edit text field and list view also. Like follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainPortal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/employeeListView"
    android:layout_width="650dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:clickable="true">
</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/empPin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/iv_start_journey_btn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/employeeListView"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="@string/add_emp_pin_hint" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_start_journey_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/employeeListView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/empPin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
    android:onClick="startJourney"
    android:src="@drawable/start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used following custom lay out for the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emp_avatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/person" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emp_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/emp_avatar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emp_avatar"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/empPin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emp_avatar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/emp_number"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emp_avatar"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/empAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/empPin"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/empPin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/empPin"
    android:text="@string/emp_add_btn" />
```

Here I post the code of Activity.java.

```
public class MainPortal extends Activity {
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_portal);
    populateEmployeeList();
    //populsteListView();

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.employeeListView);
    ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new MylistAdapter();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.employeeListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

     list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
//I ADDED ON CLICK IMPLEMENTATION HERE, BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
              }
            });


private void populateEmployeeList() {
      ...
}



private class MylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee>{


    public MylistAdapter(){
        super(MainPortal.this,R.layout.item_view,employees);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView==null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,false);
        }
        Employee currentEmployee = employees.get(position);
        //Avatar
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emp_avatar);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentEmployee.getAvatarId());
        //Employee number
        TextView emp_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emp_number);
        emp_id.setText(currentEmployee.getId());

        et = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.empPin);
        return itemView;
    }
}
}
```

Above I have posted some codes that I think important.
Can any one please help me to do this task.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the following attributes to your button

```
  android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

[ListView setOnItemClickListener not working by adding button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button)

Is your edittext taking focus on click of list item? If so remove the focus on edittext also.

Comment: @Grant the button takes focus when you click on list item. CHeck the same for edittext. if so remove the focus fro both button and edittext

Comment: @Grant you can add this to the root element in xml  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: I set EditText.setHeight(SOME VALUE) on list view on click listener. but it is not working. What can be the wrong

Comment: do you initialize editext and then do the same also you need to refersh listview by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I initialized edit text, but I don't know about this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() , please tell me how to use this. Thanks

Comment: it is used to refresh listview. suppose you change the underlying data that populated listview you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to refresh lsitview. Also why do you want to change the height of edittext dynamically. just set it to `wrap_content`

Comment: I want to initially hide the edit text and when user clicks on particular item only I want show that edit text, but it is not working.

Comment: they why do you need height settign here. you can set the view visibility to inivisible or gone depending on your need

Comment: Thank you verymuch for the information I didn't know that. Now I used
  editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
but this is also not working, do you have any idea in xml lay out I set android:visibility="invisible" for the edit text

Comment: My problem was this in my item layout: android:inputType="textMultiLine". Once removed items were click-able.

Comment: this works, but for that the property `android: clickable` must be false for the "view" in question.

Attention to the parents of the "View" to be not using "android: clickable" on. this will block the pattern selector of your list or derivative.

You can match the pattern selector with a custom selector using the property `android: foreground` like this:

`<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <FrameLayout "android: foreground="CUSTOM SELECTOR"">
    <RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout/>
  <.../>
<.../>`

Answer (score 2):

Here your edittext inside the listview is having all the focus, so this listview onClick is not working. Remove the focus from the editext box and it will start working

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
public class MainPortal extends Activity {
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    EditText et;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_portal);
        populateEmployeeList();
        //populsteListView();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.employeeListView);
        ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new MylistAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
//I ADDED ON CLICK IMPLEMENTATION HERE, BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Case setOnItemClickListener works fine in Android Versions Upto 5.1.1
But Having On Android 6.0.1. At last I found the solution
Try this
Remove these Lines from Your XML Layout

```
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ManageRequest"
android:contextClickable="true"
```

Works for Me in Android Version 6.0.1
Hope Your Problems Solved ..!!! Happy Coding :)