# Insert ListView with setOnItemClickListener in Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, arraylist, listener

I want to insert data from a EditText, in a ListView into a SQLite database. The Items have a Button, so I have already tried to fixed (like: [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155109/android-list-view-setonitemclicklistener-not-working))with

```
  android:focusable="false"
```

but the  setOnItemClickListener not work.

I have also thought to take the function onTextChanged from the ActivitiesListAdapter, but I don't know how I get access to the DatabaseHelper Object in my MainActivity.

The function setupActivityListViewAdapter in MainActivity:

```
private void setupActivityListViewAdapter() {
    activitiesListAdapter = new ActivitiesListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_activities, db.getAllActivityByDay_ID(selected_day.getDay_ID()));
    final ListView ActivitiesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_activities);
    ActivitiesListView.setAdapter(activitiesListAdapter);

    ActivitiesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Item in position " + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And setOnItemClickListener do not work?
My item_activities.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:id="@+id/activity_hours"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/activity_hours_hint"
        android:layout_weight="0.10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hours_h"
        android:id="@+id/activity_hours_h"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="5sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/activity_activity"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/activity_activity_hint" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/activity_delete"
        android:onClick="removeActivityOnClickHandler"
        android:contentDescription="@string/activity_delete"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I have this function in my ActivitiesListAdapter:

```
private void setHoursTextListeners(final ActivitiesHolder holder) {
    holder.hours.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try{
                holder.activities.setHours(Integer.valueOf(s.toString()));
            }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error reading activity hour: " + s.toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}
```

So how I can manipulate the DataBaseHelper Object from a other class, the class ActivitiesListAdapter?
And it is better to give objects single to the DataBaseHelper and not as ArrayList (I think?), so how we solve the problem.

Thanks and Kind regards.

Comment: Use `android:focusable="false"` ., `android:focusableInTouchMode="false" `and  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for your custom layout UI controls.

Comment: I do not know what I do wrong. but when I insert these all attributes to the EditTexts, then I can not enter new text in the EditTexts-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write text into your items `EditText` and make `setOnItemClickListener` work at the same time. So you should call `setOnClickListener` for your button inside adapter and make all your actions from `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Ah ok, Thankyou. But the Button is a delete button. So I want to update my table by text change.

Comment: Oh, forgot about db question. You should create your own class extending standart [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) with constructor `myDB(Context)` and call `new MyDB(context).getWritableDatabase()` for writing.

Comment: I am sorry. I should have say clear what I have. I have already a class DBHelper extending standart SQLiteOpenHelper. I work already in the MainActivity with the class and I have a object db. My question: how I get access to the object db. Or should I make a new instance of the object, so I would have a new connection to the database?

Comment: Yes, create a new instanse. It connects to file, so no need to keep reference all the lifetime of application. But operations with files (including databases) should process [not in UI thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads). And don't forget to close database all the time.