# onItemClickListener not working in TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT view

Tags: android, listview, overlay, android-windowmanager

I use Windows Manager to show huge listview. Here is code, that I use:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater ltInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ext_fill_list);

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    mWindowManager.addView(view, params);

    ArrayList<String>mItems = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ITEMS));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mItems);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("ACC", "item clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

All works fine, but OnItemClickListener not work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I belive this should be helpfull
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22705803/706833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Change LayoutParams like this:

```
mLoginPasswdDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_external_fill_by_copy, null);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lpd_params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10, 10, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FORMAT_CHANGED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, 
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

        lpd_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.RIGHT;

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mLoginPasswdDialog, lpd_params);
```