# ListView with setOnItemClickListener not work with button

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with buttons in each row in fragment, the number of buttons retrieve based on sqlite database. I want to make when button click it move to an another new activity and parse button names. But when i click the buttons nothing happens, i have already try to use this code in xml file from [ListView setOnItemClickListener not working by adding button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button), but it still not working.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Does anyone have solution? Thanks before and below is my code.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_addcard);

        List<CardType> listCardType = db.getAllCardType();
        for(CardType ct : listCardType){
            String log =  "ID: " + ct.getTypeId() + " Category Name: " + ct.getTypeCategory();
            Log.d("Result: ", log);
            categoryArray.add(ct);
        }

        adapter = new ListAdapterAddCard(getActivity(), R.layout.list_row_addcard, categoryArray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id){
                categoryName = categoryArray.get(position).getTypeCategory();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailCategory1.class);
                intent.putExtra("categoryName", categoryName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/list_addcard"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:divider="@null"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/category"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is the adapter defined in your activity or it is a different class?

Comment: @TrebiaProject actually it is in a different class

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove the following from your button xml..

```
android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

then in your custom adapter where you inflates your custom xml cell in the list, get the button reference and set the onclick listenet over there for that button.

Answer (score 0):

For me it did not work having an startActivity function within the application as within the function you don't have access to the context, you need to add the variable of the host activity. Basically I think you need to do the following:

```
 Activity host = (Activity) listView.getContext();
 Intent intent = new Intent(host, DetailCategory1.class);
 ....
 host.startActivity(intent);
```

This is what I need to do in getView method of my adapter for an standard listview.

Answer (score 0):

category_name Button is stealing the focus from the ListView item, you could either add onClick listener to the each item button or simply use TextView instead styled as Button, this is a very bad practice though and confusing to your users

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/category"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set clickable to your custom layout button in your case

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/category"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

Next, you are setting the   OnItemClickListener to the "ListView" (<< parent) itself not the 
(Button>>) children    `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){`

BUT,

you can get a reference to the **category_name** button once you have **inflated** your ListView by doing something like this;

```
Button myButton = (Button) list_addcard.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
```

If you need more help you can always visit the Android Documentation for 
ListView [ListView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i found the answer, i change the setOnClickListener to my adapter class and it's work fine for me. Thank you all for your suggestion.

```
 holder.txtCategoryName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailCategory.class);
                    int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    categoryName = categoryItems.get(pos).getTypeCategory();
                    intent.putExtra("categoryName", categoryName);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```