# Android set ListView items clickable when there's a ImageButton on it

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom listView populated with an ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>  MyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                R.layout.row,
                R.id.info,
                list
        );
```

My row layout is composed of a Textview and an ImageButton.
I've done some research and I found that Android by default doesn't allow to click on list items that already have a focusable item on them. So, as suggested, I added the following attributes to my button layout:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Unfortunately, the problem persists. Does anyone knows what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to make ListView focusable `android:focusable="true"` and Button not focusable `android:focusable="false"` ?

Comment: Posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button

Comment: @VoodooCoder, yes already tried, but without luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my own question.

I need to add this line in the row layout:

```
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

With this line, I explicitly block the focusability of the child elements of the row layout.
 That was tricky because apparently only the imageButtons have this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

for `ImageButton`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the button attribute in your xml file:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

and remove:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

and it should work.. It'll be clickable, just won't gain focus.

However, you use `android:clickable="true"`  for non-clickable items such as views.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `ImageButton` objects

```
    android:setFocusable="false"
    android:setClickable="false"
    android.setLongClickable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `ImageButton` like this:

```
android:setFocusable="false"
android:setClickable="true"
```

And add `OnClickListener` to your `ImageButton` and `onItemClickListener` to your `ListView`. I think it will work.