# Listview setOnItemClickListener not working?

Tags: android, listadapter, onitemclicklistener

Whenever I tap on listview nothing pops up.

This is the on onCreate:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    String[] Data = {"Sunday 20/44", "dsd  65 /00", "defef","dddf","sdsdsd","dsdsdsd","3e3we"};


    List lstData = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Data));
    forecastAdp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
            lstData

    );

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewForecast);
    listView.setAdapter(forecastAdp);



   listView.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           String main = listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),main, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
```

Comment: you might want to see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button
hope it helps ;)

Comment: please do some re-search around it, lots of stuff related to on-click <list view> is already present in stack over flow

Comment: My point is this , my list view is not recognising my tap

Comment: Did u try mine solution??

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
String main = listView.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

to

```
String main = forecastAdp.get(position).(your adapter textView name where you are storing value).
```

Answer (score 0):

Why making it complex, try to pass the position direct in the Toast body:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),Data[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```