# Button click not working in list view

Tags: android, android-listview

My xml is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llMainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContentTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/downloadProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:max="@integer/downloadProgressMax"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_notificationContent_download"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:text="Download"
    android:textColor="#ffff1205"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

and my adapter class is -

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup  parent){
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(
                    R.layout.notification_listview_item, null);

            // convertView =
            // inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_listview_item,
            // parent, false);

        }
        TextView txtContent = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
        txtContent.setTag(position);
        TextView txtContentTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtContentTitle);
        Button btn_notificationContent_download = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_notificationContent_download);
        ProgressBar downloadProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
        if (isDownloading && (download != null)) {
            downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            downloadProgressBar.setProgress(download.getProgress());
            downloadProgressBar.invalidate();
        } else {
            downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = AppService.getAppService().getLanguageJsonObject();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        if (strVersion.contentEquals("0")) {
            String msg = null;
            if (obj != null) {
                try {
                    msg = obj.getString(LanguageTags.TAG_DOWNLOAD);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("") || msg == null) {
                msg = "Download";
            }
            btn_notificationContent_download.setText(msg);
        } else {
            String msg = null;
            if (obj != null) {
                try {
                    msg = obj.getString(LanguageTags.TAG_UPDATE);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("") || msg == null) {
                msg = "Update";
            }
            btn_notificationContent_download.setText(msg);
        }
        txtContent.setTag(position);
        btn_notificationContent_download.setTag(position);
        btn_notificationContent_download
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();

                        UrlBuilder builder = AppService.getAppService()
                                .getUrlBuilder();
                        String filePath = builder
                        String contentId = Content
                                .getContentId(notificationList
                                        .get(mPosition));
                        if (contentId == null) {
                            contentId = Content.getId(notificationList
                                    .get(mPosition));
                        }
                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(notificationList.get(position));
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AppService.getAppService()
                        .getApplicationContext(),   abc.class);
                intent.putExtra(AppKeys.KEY_JSON_CONTENT,
                        ((JSONObject) v.getTag()).toString());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                AppService.getAppService().getApplicationContext()
                        .startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

My button and the convertview click listeners not working. Dont know where I am wrong.. It was working before but now it just stuck. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: add this line to your item layout android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: Seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button

Answer (score 0):

Please put this on button in layout

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ok @MuhammedRefaat i will take care in future.thanks for supporting

Comment: thank you for understanding, the point here is that people in SO must gain knowledge and learn with every post they do, so solving only the problem without any clarification doesn't provide that, just a little declaration why he has to do that will be great. thanks :)