# onItemCickListener not responding to click on a Grid View item

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener

I've got two `Activities`, the first one lets a user search an article and then returns the results into a `gridview` on the same `activity`. On clicking one of the resulting articles, a `second activity` should be launched. I know the `click` isn't happening because the `toasts` and `log.d` aren't firing either.

The `gridview`, displaying the results is in the `launcher activity` and the result items are a `XML template`.

I've  read the following thread ( [ListView setOnItemClickListener not working by adding button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button) ) but I can't understand what `layout` everyone is referring to.

**Project layout:**

- 2 Activities. `Activity A` has two `XML`s associated with it, the
  `activity XML` and the one that houses my `gridview`. This second one is
  where I've been focusing much of my attempts.

  `Activity A` should launch `Activity B` via `Intent`.

  `Activity B` also has two `XML`s associated with it.. but I can't `click`
  through to it, hence they aren't relevant at the moment.

  ***attempts:***
- Add the property `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root layout within the template for the item.

  *I interpret that as the layout that houses my `gridview` (my `launcher activity`)... When I do this, my `textView` for the search doesn't come into focus, which seems logical since I'm telling the layout to block focus on all descendants.*
- Set `gridview paramter: android:focussable="true"` . Also, not the solution.
- I'm setting the `ClickListener` **after** setting the `adapter`. So this should not be interfering with the `listener`. (*clarification*)
- Try setting your `buttons` (or any other `views` you want to handle click inside a `list item`) like this:

> android:focusable="false"
>
> android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

*Again, why would setting `focus false` on something that's going to handle a click work?!*

**Questions**: What is considered the "root layout within the template for the item" or as someone else referred to it: "main (first level) layout" ? Is my interpretation of this above, correct?

Setting blocksDecendants on the gridview will ... invariably set the items I'm returning to be blocked, no?

**Launcher Activity layout:**

```
  <include layout="@layout/content_search" />
```

**Content Search Activity layout:**  Launcher activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.SearchActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_search">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etQuery"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:hint="@string/hints" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onArticleSearch"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gvResults"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:numColumns="3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**item article result layout:**  this template gets populated in the gridview and on click should launch new activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="There will be a lot of content here..."
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**On Item Click Listener**

```
   // hook up listener for grid click
        gvResults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                 // create an intent to display the article
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
                // get the article to display
                Article article = articles.get(position);
                // pass in that article to the intent
                i.putExtra("url", article.getWebUrl());
                // launch the activity
                startActivity(i);
                Log.d("DEBUG ", i.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got this far..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You want the focusable items in the list item layout to be non-focussable because they will otherwise attempt to take focus rather than the list item you are clicking on.

Could you show the code you have set up for the list view layout as well as the list item layout?

Comment: The root layout of the item is the outermost view group of the XML file defining the layout for a single list item.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.
Please add the layouts used, as well as the class / listeners that are being used. It is likely that onTouch is being consumed, by some View in higher hierachy, or that is being set after the class is instantiated