# listview.setOnItemClickListener not working using CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to display a Toast when I click the Item list of my listview.

my listview works well but the problem is no action will done after clicking the item of my listview.

here is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

**ClientCursorAdapter .java**

```
class ClientCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    Context context;
    public ClientCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,viewGroup,false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        TextView artist = view.findViewById(R.id.Artist);
        ToggleButton music = view.findViewById(R.id.minus_one);
        ToggleButton favorite = view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE")));
        artist.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ARTIST")));

    }
}
```

Comment: add your "row_layout" layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your buttons (or any other views you want to handle click inside a list item) like this:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6703671/1084174

Comment: Yes this is the best answer for me.it's work,

Answer (score 1):

If your listview row contains clickable or focusable view items, the `onItemClick` won't be called. You can either set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your layout. E.g.,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">    

</LinearLayout>
```

or set `android:focusable="false"` to your item, e.g., ImageButton.

Comment: Thanks. this code works too. :-)

Comment: I was only able to get mine to work by adding the android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"... making each button focusable false and focusableintouchmode false did not work